# PostgreSQL Using string_agg with count

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgresql-14

I have to create a query to show **group_id** and the *list with the main user's subjects and number of people from this group per subjects*.

Hello, I agree that it's difficult to understand. Sorry for that.
There's some steps to make it easy to understand.
Here is used one table(**dm_group gr**) for **two** facts:

1. To show to is discipline leader (gr.entity_type='Group' and gr.group_type='TRAINER'), so I can identify only teachers.
   In this case gr.name will be teacher's name.
2. But every user has at least one line in dm_group gr, which shows what is his the main subject/direction (gr.entity_type = 'Discipline'). In this case gr.name will be exactly the name of the main user's subject.

So, one user, as a teacher forms a group to what students can be assigned. And generally, every user has a main subject he is also assigned to.
Finally, I should identify all teacher's ids with the list of all their students subjects with number of user's.

1. So, first of all we identify **all the teachers** (select gr.id where group_type='TRAINER')
2. Next in **dm_user_to_group utg** we find all users assigned to each teacher(**select u.id where utg.id = gr.id**)
3. So the next step is *tricky*, knowing all user_ids for each teacher, I have to find all group ids for this users to find in dm_group their main subject(**where gr.entity_type = 'Discipline'**) and finally to get how much people have this or that subject as the main in each teacher's group.

Result should be like: group_id| subject(#);subject(#);..., where subject is the number of people from group and related to concrete subject.

I wrote smth like this:

*But it doesn't work as expected..

```
SELECT tr.id AS "Trainer ID",
       string_agg(info.name || '(' || info.number || ')',
                  '; ' order by info.name
           ) AS "Discipline Counts"
FROM (
         SELECT d.name, count(u.userid) as number
         FROM dm_group tr
                  LEFT JOIN
              dm_user_to_group utg ON tr.id = utg.group_id
                  LEFT JOIN
              dm_user u ON utg.user_id = u.userid
                  LEFT JOIN
              dm_group d ON u.userid = d.id AND d.entity_type = 'Discipline'
         group by d.name, u.userid) info
         full outer JOIN dm_group tr on tr.name = info.name
where tr.group_type = 'TRAINER'
GROUP BY tr.id
ORDER BY tr.id;
```

Tables used:

`dm_group`:

```
create table dm_group (
  entity_type  varchar(15) not null,
  id           bigserial primary key,
  description  text
  name         varchar(255),
  group_type   varchar(255)
);
```

`dm_user_to_group`:

```
create table dm_user_to_group (
  group_id bigint constraint fk_gr_to_u references dm_group,
  user_id  bigint constraint fk_us_to_gr references dm_user
);
```

Comment: Why did you tag Postgres 9.3 and 9.4? What is your actual version? Something more recent I would hope? Also, show a valid `CREATE TABLE` statement. That beats all vague descriptions.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your question. As it is my first question here, it's the only versions appeared in list. I use 14 postgres

Comment: I see. That's misleading as "9" sorts before "10" in that smart sort. All versions are there. I fixed that for you.

Comment: group:
create table dm_group
(
    entity_type            varchar(15) not null,
    id                     bigserial
        primary key,
    description            text,
    name                   varchar(255),
    group_type             varchar(255));

user_to_group:

create table user_to_group
(
    group_id bigint
        constraint fk_gr_to_u
            references group,
    user_id  bigint
        constraint fk_us_to_gr
            references user
);

Comment: Please [edit] the question to present all info there. And use a legal table name. "group" is a reserved word that would require double-quoting. So go with "dm_group".

Comment: I agree, I've applied changes

Comment: Can't use `group` as table alias, either. :) Please show the statement you actually tried.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I've added my statement

Comment: And why would you join from `dm_user.id` to `dm_group.id`. Please present a consistent question next time. Gotta go.

Comment: Because user can present a group or can be part of it. So dm_group_id can define user's group, where other user's can be included in. Hope you will find time

Comment: So group name can have entity_type Group and its name will be user's name who conduct it. But if entity_type is Discipline it shows with what subject user is related to..

Answer (score 0):

By combining subqueries and the string_agg function, you can get the desired results. However, you must modify your SQL query in a few specific ways. Here is an illustration of how to accomplish it:

```
SELECT
    gr.id AS group_id,
    string_agg(d.name || '(' || COALESCE(CAST(sub.count AS text), '0') || ')', '; ') AS "Discipline Counts"
FROM
    dm_group gr
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        g.id AS group_id,
        u.id AS user_id,
        d.name AS discipline_name
    FROM
        dm_user_to_group utg
    JOIN
        dm_group g ON utg.group_id = g.id
    JOIN
        dm_user u ON utg.user_id = u.id
    LEFT JOIN
        dm_group d ON u.id = d.id AND d.entity_type = 'Discipline'
    WHERE
        g.group_type = 'Math'
) AS sub ON gr.id = sub.group_id
GROUP BY
    gr.id
ORDER BY
    gr.id;
```

This should return a list of group_ids and the subjects they are linked with, together with the number of users for each subject related to the 'Math' group type. Change the table and column names to correspond to your actual database schema.

Hope it works :)

Comment: Hello, I'm really sorry for bad task description. I rewrote it again. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please review my query

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess:

```sql
SELECT id, string_agg(dis_ct, '; ') AS "Discipline Counts"
FROM  (
   SELECT tr.id, d.name || '(' || count(DISTINCT d.id) || ')' AS dis_ct
   FROM   dm_group           tr
   LEFT   JOIN user_to_group ug ON ug.group_id = tr.id
   LEFT   JOIN dm_user       u  ON u.id = ug.user_id
   LEFT   JOIN dm_group      d  ON d.id = u.id
                               AND d.entity_type = 'Discipline'
   WHERE  tr.group_type = 'TRAINER'
   GROUP  BY tr.id, d.name
   ORDER  BY tr.id, d.name
   ) sub
GROUP  BY tr.id
ORDER  BY tr.id;
```

Aggregate counts in a subquery. Then aggregate the desired string format at the outer level.

If no matching row in `d` is found, the count would be 0. But concatenating that to `d.name` (which then is `null`, consequently) removes these noise counts anyway, so no `FILTER` needed.

Comment: I'm really sorry for that. I rewrote all description and added possible steps. I hope it will really help. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please review my query

Comment: @mss Still confusing. Not sure your relational model is ideal. I adapted my guess slightly.